# IPython: How to save 2 ranges of lines with the save magic command?

Tags: python, save, ipython

I'd like to save something like 1-4 and 8-14.

```
save two-line-ranges.py 1-4, 8-14
```

Currently I can only save either or the whole range 1-14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
save two-line-ranges.py 1-4 8-14
```